# looping a program back to the begining?

Tags: python-3.x

Hi i'm writing a dice rolling program and would like to know how to loop it back to the begining of the program at the end. Any solutions will be much apreciated. Thanks

```
import random
while True:
     dice_type = int(input("would you like to roll a 4,6 or 12 sided dice:"))
     if dice_type in [4, 6, 12]:
         break
     print("Sorry that is not the correct input")

score = random.randint(1, dice_type)

print ("You have chosen to throw a %d-sided dice" %dice_type)
print ("You rolled a %d" %score)
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your statements in another while-loop?

Comment: Wrap everything in a while True loop. Just write `While True:` under `import random` and indent everything below it.

Comment: Yeah i have tried that and it just breaks the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
while True:
    while True:
        dice_type = int(input("would you like to roll a 4,6 or 12 sided dice:"))
        if dice_type in [4, 6, 12]:
            break
        print("Sorry that is not the correct input")

    score = random.randint(1, dice_type)

    print ("You have chosen to throw a %d-sided dice" %dice_type)
    print ("You rolled a %d" %score)
```

will let the player choose a die type and show the score an infinite number of times (barring heat death of universe, Ctrl-C, or equipment or power failure )